# Range Partition in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to create a ranged partitioned table in an Azure SQL Database with rolling monthly partitions. So everything from a January (no matter what year) should be within one partition.

The table contains logging information for ETL processes and to ease the housekeeping I'd like to be able to truncate partitions from time to time.

In Oracle I would do it like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_log (
   log_id      NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
   log_txt     VARCHAR2(1000),
   insert_date DATE 
) 
PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_CHAR(insert_date, 'MM')) (
  partition m1 values less than ('02'), 
  partition m2 values less than ('03'), 
  partition m3 values less than ('04'),
  partition m4 values less than ('05'),
  partition m5 values less than ('06'),
  partition m6 values less than ('07'),
  partition m7 values less than ('08'),
  partition m8 values less than ('09'),
  partition m9 values less than ('10'),
  partition m10 values less than ('11'),
  partition m11 values less than ('12'),
  partition m12 values less than ('13'),
  partition mmax values less than (MAXVALUE)
);
```

And use a ALTER TABLE TRUNCATE PARTITION for housekeeping to get rid of everything older than let's say 4 months.

What I found out so far: if I create a partition function for the ranges, the column that contains the range must be part of the primary key. Is there any way to circumvent that?

This dos not work:

```sql
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION logRangePF1 (int)  
    AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) ;  
GO  

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME logRangePS1  
    AS PARTITION logRangePF1  
    ALL TO ('PRIMARY') ;  
GO  

CREATE TABLE dbo.logPartitionTable (
    log_id INT PRIMARY KEY , 
    log_text nvarchar(1000), 
    insert_date datetime,
    partition_column as datepart(month, insert_date) PERSISTED
    )  
    ON logRangePS1 ( partition_column ) ;  
GO
```

I appreciate any hint on how to archive this in an Azure SQL Database.

Thanks

Comment: "I want to create a ranged partitioned table in an Azure SQL Database with rolling monthly partitions" - partitioned tables are rarely the solution to the real problem. You might have an XY problem.

Comment: @MitchWheat: thanks for the hint. I added a problem description to the post.

Comment: Partition functions and schemes are supported in SQL Azure as long as you use the primary filegroup.  What error are you getting?

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT as I wrote, it the partitioning column must be part of the PK: "Column 'partition_column' is partitioning column of the index 'PK__logPartitionTabl__4B56165E'. Partition columns for a unique index must be a subset of the index key."

Comment: @Hanebambel - ahh, I see.  uniqueness enforcement is done at the b-tree level.  Partitioned tables will have N heaps/b-trees/etc.  So, I suggest you remove the PRIMARY KEY from the create table defn originally and see if it works to partition the way you want.  Then you can add a specific constraint to have a PK on (logid, partition_column) as one possible workaround for you here.